# Need help on multiselect for bootstrap typehead using ajax source?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I want`s to use bootstrap Typehead for auto fill but I am getting confused, I am using below JS for this can any body help on this.
My Requirement is :
What ever user fill using typehead should come into textarea ($myTextarea) .

I wants to get selected values into a textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
$.ajax({
url: '/test/typehead/data.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: 'query=' + query,
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
process(data);

}
});
}

});
updater: function(item) {
    $myTextarea.append(item, ' ');
    return '';
}
});
```

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Solved....Some Syntax error

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $myTextarea = $('#myTextarea');
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
$.ajax({
url: '/test/typehead/data.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: 'query=' + query,
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
process(data);

}
});
},
updater: function(item) {
$myTextarea.append(item, ' ');
return '';
}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {

                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "url",
                        data: '{ "query": "' + query + '"}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //use data.d in case of asp.net
                            return process(data);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert("Failure");
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("There seems to be an error");
                        }
                    });
                },
              updater: function(item) {
              $myTextarea.append(item, ' ');
               return item;
             }
            });
        });
```

This should help you out, 
For further reading read [this](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/)
Cheers!!!